# Read 2d barcode from scanned pdf (image) via jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, barcode, code39

Anyone out there aware of any way to read a CODE39 barcode from a scanned 1 page .pdf via jQuery or javascript?

My goal is to be able to pass the url path of the .pdf to a function that returns the data string encoded in the barcode on the scanned .pdf.

I am not versed on Java so the ZXing is a bit over my head.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't deal with files directly with javascript. You could pass the path to some server-side utility that could maybe do what you want. I have no idea how that would work on the server-side though, but I am providing this insight so that you redirect your search/question.

Comment: Actually _you can_ deal directly with files using `FileReader` or AJAX, but then again, you wouldn't have any API support. Something has been made for images, but definitely not for PDFs. And Javascript would be a terrible choice for this kind of tasks, due of its performances.

Comment: I found this...which is exactly what I need to do. http://inliteresearch.com/barcode-recognition/read-1d-barcode-pro.php       Their online tool works great. I just need help integrating their code into my site..as the sdk is over my head.